# What's the racoon doing in my apple?

Tags: snow-leopard, activity-monitor

I'm not normally one for paraniodly checking my activity monitor for rogue processes; but this one just has my internal nature-watcher all curious. Why is there a racoon running under my root user? What's it doing? Foraging? Looking for nuts and berries? Staring at headlights?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/racoon.8.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/8/racoon):

> **racoon** speaks the IKE (ISAKMP/Oakley) key management protocol, to establish security associations with
>   other hosts.  The SPD (Security Policy Database) in the kernel usually triggers **racoon**.  **racoon** usually
>   sends all informational messages, warnings and error messages to syslogd(8) with the facility
>   LOG_DAEMON and the priority LOG_INFO.  Debugging messages are sent with the priority LOG_DEBUG.  You
>   should configure syslog.conf(5) appropriately to see these messages.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation link of the main answer is now dead, but you can still run:

```
man racoon
```

and obtain an answer:

> racoon is used to setup and maintain an IPSec tunnel or transport channel, between two devices, over which network traffic is conveyed
> securely. [...]